# A few questions regarding web based c#programming with visual studio 2010 and mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm making a web based inventory database that is connected to mysql, and I currently have a purchase order(PO) page for incoming stocks, delivery receipt(DR) page for outgoing stocks and a stock list page.

In the PO page is a grid view of my PO table connected to mysql with edit and delete enabled and the edit is linked to a separate page. Same goes with the DR page. Stock page has a grid view of Stock table connected to mysql with only edit enabled.

I have a separate add new page and edit page for PO and DR. Both add and edit pages have details view in them. Here are my questions.

**1.** How do I automatically insert records that are inserted in the add page using details view for both PO and DR to Stock table. My stock table looks like this:

Stock_ID | Date | PO_ID | DR_ID | Product_ID | Stock_In | Stock_Out | Stock_Balance |

What I want to happen is that when I enter either a new DR or PO, it'll go to the stock table automatically as well as their respective tables and the stock balance will adjust automatically.

**2.** In my details view of add new PO, I edited the details view so that when you choose a supplier and product you get to choose from a drop down list that is connected to their respective table, how do I limit what product the user can choose in regards to the supplier he /she chooses. Let's say that I choose supplier 1 and the products he supplies are products 1 and 2. What I want to happen is that when I choose supplier 1 the products that I can choose are limited to products 1 and 2.

This is the link to my AddPO source code

http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=5AaqHSc4

This is the link to my AddPO.cs source code

http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=Mz8GdLfx

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

1. The `InsertCommand` should be fired when a `LinkButton` with `CommandName="Insert"` is clicked, which you have at the bottom of the form.  You can try querying any error messages during the `ItemInserted` event using `DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs.ExceptionHandled` to check if there was an unhandled exception, and `DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs .Exception` to get the details of that exception.  Does it work if you remove all of your logic you have placed in the `ItemInserting` event?
2. Your `SqlDataSource` for the products `DropDown` should have a parameter of `SupplierId`, and your `SelectCommand` should filter based on that parameter.

Example code for `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1"
        SelectCommand="Select * from Products Where SupplierId=@SupplierId">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="SupplierId" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Example binding code (replace with correct control id's):

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(
       object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    DropDown SupplierDropDown = 
        MyDetailsView.FindControl("SupplierDropDown") as DropDown;
    e.Arguments["SupplierId"] = SupplierDropDown.SelectedValue;
}
```

**Old**

1. If your data is connected to a `DataSource` control, set the `InsertStatement` or `OnInsert` event to the appropriate code to handle inserting according to your spec.  If you're binding the `DetailsView` programmatically, then you will need to handle the `ItemInserting` event of the DetailsView, or use custom logic in your submit button.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.iteminserting.aspx for more information.
2. Use a `ControlParameter` on your data source of the products `DropDown`, tied the selected value of the Supplier `DropDown`.  Then set `AutoPostBack=True` on the suppliers `DropDown`, so any time a selection is made, the products list is updated accordingly.

Comment: How do I add a control parameter?

Comment: Can you show a code snippet of how your DetailsView is defined?  The solution depends on the way you are defining your data source.

Comment: Can I just give you a link to a .txt document of my source code?

Comment: Sure.  Edit your question and post a link so that others can see it too.  You can use a service like http://pastebin.com/ so it's accessible in the future.

Comment: I'm a little confused of what you mean, so what I have to do then is transfer the code from the DetailsView ItemInserting to the DetailsView ItemInserted? Please bare with me as I'm new at this.

Comment: @DarkXaldin: No I'm not suggesting changing your current code necessarily.  I'm suggesting a few methods for debugging.  We don't know what the problem is yet, so what are we supposed to attack?  You have code to insert, why isn't it working now?  That's what you need to figure out.

Comment: I don't have access to a testing environment, but someone who does could possibly load in your code and try to track it down as well.

Comment: The error I get when I try to insert a new record to the table is Fatal error encountered during command execution, I'm thinking this has something to do with the sql code.

Comment: Would it better help you find out what I'm doing wrong if I gave you the whole project solution and the mysql backup?

Comment: @DarkXaldin: for starters, I would add that error message to your question as well.  That's a really important part of knowing what to focus on.  Include the whole error message, and possibly stack trace / line numbers if available.

Comment: @DarkXaldin: I don't think the whole project solution is necessary.  If I were in a position to dig in deeper, I would load your code into a solution myself, create a mock database, try to reproduce the error you are having, and see what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, so what exactly do you need?